# Capture variable nginx if statement

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am working on a site i have since long time and i would kike to redirect old useless pages to a category page listing relevant articles.

I have seen n my google search console the following url :

**https://www.example.com/Greece/sport%20?page=55**

I would like to get :

**https://www.example.com/greece.html?page=55**

I am using nginx with a custom script that imposes in the server setting to indicate for which domain the redirection has to be done.
I am trying to figure out the way to do it and the following code is not giving me the right  redirection.
I would appreciate if anybody could give me a hint.

```
location ^~  /(.*)/  {
  if ($host ~* ^(www\.)?(mysite\.com)$) {
     return 301 $scheme://$host/$1.html;
   }
   return 404;
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this config:

```
server {
   ...
   server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
   
   location ~* ^(/[^/]+)/ {
       return 301 $scheme://$host$1.html$is_args$args;
   }
   ....
}
```

The regular expression in location block you can modify as you need.

Comment: Thanks It would have worked if i did not have this specific constraint related to the hosting environment on the sever. https://github.com/omega8cc/boa/blob/6f7be76c8d1a41a1ee6203484aa40c56631e8885/docs/HINTS.txt#L36